# Azure Devops SQL DB Deploy task fails during the login process

Tags: database, ssl, azure-devops

I have an Azure Devops pipeline with a task to run a migration script with every deployment. However, I get the error below during the SQL DB Deploy step:

"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)"

The database is served from Amazon's RDS and their certificate is valid (not expired until 2024). I can't find a way to add the Certificate Authority to Azure Devops to fix this error, or at least this would be my understanding of the error message.

I tried a few different options I found regarding a breaking change that Azure Devops introduced in regards to DB connections. I know that Encrypt is set to true by default now. I tried setting it to false and setting the TrustServerCertificate flag to true in the connection string as a test, but it didn't work either.

[image of the DB Deploy task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovEzy.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check with the following things to fix the issue:

1. Use Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server **`18.x`**.
2. Set the value **`of Encrypt/Use Encryption for Data setting`** to be **`No`** or **`Optional`** to the connection string.
3. Add **`Encrypt=True`** to the connection string.
4. Add **`Trusted_Connection=True`** to the connection string.
5. As you had tried, add **`TrustServerCertificate=true`** to the connection string.

For more details, you can reference the documentation "[**The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/certificate-chain-not-trusted?tabs=ole-db-driver-19)".

Comment: Hi, I tried the options 2 - 5 and they didn't work. How could I use the OLE DB Driver in the Azure pipeline? I edited the post with an image of what my pipeline looks like. Thank you.

Comment: @HugoMelo, What type of agent are you using to run the pipeline jobs? Microsoft-hosted agents or your self-hosted agents? And you may need to change the OLE DB Driver on the machine of your SQL Server.

Comment: I'm using a Microsoft-hosted agent. My SQL Server instance is in Amazon's RDS at the moment.